# Faking an app crash in android

Tags: android, crash

I just came across an app called `App Locker II: Fake Crash`, it fakes an app crash. You just add the app (say WhatsApp) to the list in `App Locker II: Fake Crash` and next time when you try to launch `WhatsApp`, a screen comes up saying `The application WhatsApp (com.whatsapp) has stopped unexpectedly`.
How does this actually work ? Is the crash faked or `WhatsApp` actually crashes down ?
I would be delighted to know how does this work.

Comment: You could check the LogCat. If there's an Exception, the LogCat will show it and you can see exactly what type of Exception is being created.

Comment: The process id should been checked too. It is not too hard to face a logcat output too. Just the process id should been impossible to fake.

Answer (score 2):

I think that app observes the running processes and creates on start of such a "blacklisted app" a custom dialog with that message you quoted above. In a second step the app will been closed or the home launcher is started. However the reviews point out that it does not work very well.